# Arch Linux Activate NVIDIA Graphic Card

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, graphics

How can I activate my NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960M for Minecraft? When I type in

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
```

I want to play minecraft with my GTX card. I tried "env DRI_PRIME=1 minecraft-launcher". It started normally but when you press F3 ingame then it shows you the used graphic processor and it shows the intel one. 
But how can I activate it now?
Greets

Comment: What do you mean by "activating" the graphics card?

Comment: That Minecraft or any other programm uses the NVIDIA card

Comment: Do you already have a graphical interface, or are you in text mode and expect the game to start the graphics by itself?

Comment: I have Cinnamon as de

Comment: Please go beck to your question and explain what happens - and what doesn't happen - and what you expected too happen. What did you do? We aren't with you and can't see what you see.

Comment: I want to start the Application minecraft-launcher with my GTX 960M and not with the Intel Graphics. I tried a command "env DRI_PRIME=1 minecraft launcher" but that didn't worked

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/534412/edit) to include this information. Don't write in the comments - it's all too easy for other people to miss it.

Comment: While you're there, don't write "that didn't work". TELL US what happened. What error messages you got. What you expected to happen. What didn't happen.

Comment: Does the system have the drivers for both GPUs ready for use? What is the output of  `xrandr --listproviders`? Does it list both GPUs?

Comment: I have the intel and the nouvea driver installed. No it shows only the Intel GPU